# How do I write tests for a transformed stream in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream

I have a Provider which has a method which takes data from Firebase as a stream, transforms it to a list and returns a `Stream<List<Model>>` . I'm trying to write a test where I want to check if the items in the `List` are the same as I expect them to be. How can I do that?

My Current Code:

```
test('getContacts returns a empty list when there is no contact',() async{
      when(sharedPreferencesMock.get(any)).thenReturn('uid'); //mock the sharedprefs
      documentSnapshot = DocumentSnapshotMock();  //mock documentsnapshot
      when(documentSnapshot.exists).thenReturn(true); // this is done to pass the getUidByUsername method
      documentReference = DocumentReferenceMock(documentSnapshotMock: documentSnapshot);
      documentReference.setData({
        'uid':'uid',
        'contacts':[]  // setting the usename in the data already so that duplicate contact exception is thrown
      });
      userDataProvider.getContacts().asBroadcastStream().listen((data){
        expect(data.length,0);
      });

    });
```

And the provider method

```
  @override
  Stream<List<Contact>> getContacts() {
    CollectionReference userRef = fireStoreDb.collection(Paths.usersPath);
    DocumentReference ref =
        userRef.document(SharedObjects.prefs.get(Constants.sessionUid));


    return ref.snapshots().transform(StreamTransformer<DocumentSnapshot, List<Contact>>.fromHandlers(handleData: (documentSnapshot, sink) async{
      List<String> contacts;
      if (documentSnapshot.data['contacts'] == null) {
        ref.updateData({'contacts': []});
        contacts = List();
      } else {
        contacts = List.from(documentSnapshot.data['contacts']);
      }
      List<Contact> contactList = List();
      for (String username in contacts) {
        print(username);
        String uid = await getUidByUsername(username);
        DocumentSnapshot contactSnapshot = await userRef.document(uid).get();
        contactList.add(Contact.fromFirestore(contactSnapshot));
      }
      sink.add(contactList);
    }));

  }
```

**Update:**

```
 StreamController streamController = StreamController<List<Contact>>();
      StreamSink<List<Contact>> sink = streamController.sink;
      Stream<List<Contact>> stream = streamController.stream;
      stream.listen((List<Contact> list){
        expect(list.length,1);
      });
      userDataProvider.mapDocumentToContact(userCollection, userRef, documentSnapshot, sink);
      streamController.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the lambda function that you currently pass to the StreamTansformer a separate function and test that.
If you want to test the full function there is a Firebase mock package on pub.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I extracted the lambda function out and wrote the test for it. It's passing now. I have updated the question with the code snippet. Can you check if it's the right way of doing it?

Comment: Done. Thanks @Thomas